# Laravel SQL Or Eloquent Advanced Query

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I need to make an advanced query in Laravel hopefully using Eloquent to make that a collection but a query builder or raw normal SQL query is acceptable.

I have users table with User model having relation:

```
public function roles()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'users_roles');
}
```

I have roles table, with Role model having relation:

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'users_roles');
}
```

So, I have users_roles table with columns `[user_id, role_id]`, so I can have users with multiple roles

I want to get all users with roles different from a certain role, for example get all users that are all kind of roles except role of id 1

how to do that?

Comment: what have you attempted so far?

Comment: @lagbox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76242881/laravel-sql-or-eloquent-advanced-query/76243118#76243118

Comment: what have you attempted **BEFORE** asking your question on here ... you have to attempt to solve your problem before asking (which includes doing research)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix was:

```
$roleId = 1;
$users = User::with($withArray)->whereDoesntHave('roles', function ($query) use ($roleId) {
                    $query->where('roles.id', $roleId);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a where clause to `withWhereHas` to defined rules on which models to return depending on relations, like so:

```php
$usersWhereRoleIsNotOne = User::query()
    ->withWhereHas('roles', function(Builder $builder){
        $builder->whereNot('id', 1);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Argument #1 ($builder) must be of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany given

Comment: I have this error